# Reference to raster list

Tags: python, raster, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I am writing my first Python plugin. There was a problem during work. The plugin is designed to select a raster and calculate the statistics for the area bounded by the vector. I have created a list of rasters, but I do not know how to refer to the selected raster in the further part of the plugin to calculate statistics for it. The following code is created.

List of raster layers:

```
def create_layer_list(self):
    ''' Build list of layers'''
    self.dialog.chooseCombo.clear()
    self.layers = list(self.registry.mapLayers().values())
    #self.layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layer_list = [""]+[layer.name() for layer in self.layers]
    self.dialog.chooseCombo.addItems(layer_list)
```

Main function for counting statistics:

```
def get_statistic(self):

      index2 = self.dialog.chooseCombo.currentIndex()
      rlayer = self.layers[index2].layer_list()
      provider = rlayer.dataProvider()

      for band in range(1, rlayer.bandCount() + 1):
        stats = provider.bandStatistics(band, QgsRasterBandStats.All, self.extent, 0)
        min = stats.minimumValue
        max = stats.maximumValue
        mean = stats.mean
        statsGathered = stats.statsGathered
        results= print ('min: {:.2f}, max: {:.2f}, mean: {:.2f}, statsGathered: {:.2f}'.format(min, max,mean,statsGathered)) 
        self.dialog.textlabelLayout.setText(results)
```

Unfortunately, Python throws an error when indexing ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try referencing the selected layer by name:

```
def get_statistic(self):
    selected_layer = self.dialog.chooseCombo.currentText()
    rlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(selected_layer)[0]
    provider = rlayer.dataProvider()
```

Comment: I changed QgsMapLayerRegistry to QgsProject and it worked! Thank You!

Comment: @iza4400 - Apologies, you are indeed correct :)